# Linux embedded sched_setscheduler workload

Tags: embedded, scheduling, affinity

I am developing a testing approach for embedded software, and would like to test it on a POSIX based, real world application that uses scheduler Linux functions (e.g. sched_setscheduler).

It is relatively easy to find open source software that is using POSIX threads and locks (e.g. http://ctrace.sourceforge.net). However, I cannot find any real world application to use Linux scheduling as well. Google drives me in a direction of WCET calculation.

Does anyone know any open source, embedded, POSIX based software, that uses scheduling and affinity Linux functions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/rt-tests/rt-tests.git/. and here: http://elinux.org/Realtime_Testing_Best_Practices These are artificial test sets for realtime testing Linux kernels. Basically they work on parallel and prioritized CPU load, scheduling and missing computation deadlines.